# how to get value from 1 side of 1 to n with condition on n side of relation in ef core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

i have two classes like below

```
class order
{
  int Id;

  List<Payment> Paymants;
}

class Payment
{
  int Id;

  string Token;

  int OrderId;

  Order Order;
}
```

and i use ef core code first approach.

tokens are unique and want to get related order from DB by token related to it.

I've tried

```
 
 ​            ​var order = _dbContext.Orders
.Include(i=>i.Payments)
.SingleAsync(b=>b.Payments.Contains(c=>c.vandarToken == Token));
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: What did you do? your question is very incomprehensible. it needs more detail.

Comment: every order has 1 to n payment and each payment has a unique key named tokan , I need to retrieve order based on token. i have token i need related order from db .

Comment: Have you heard about `Include`?